# Use of Response.End in an MVC3 Action

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3

I'm trying to do something like [this article](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/community/blogs/craig/archive/2004/07/24/1699.aspx) suggests in my MVC3 site.  However, I'm not sure I can use the Response.End in my Action.

My question is, how can I return a 401 status code from my Action if the HttpContext.User == null?

```
public ActionResult WinUserLogOn(string returnUrl) {
        var userName = string.Empty;

        if (HttpContext.User == null) {
            //This will force the client's browser to provide credentials
            Response.StatusCode = 401;
            Response.StatusDescription = "Unauthorized";
            Response.End();
            return View("LogOn"); //<== ????
        }
        else {
           //Attempt to Log this user against Forms Authentication
        }
```

Comment: What seems to be the problem with the code that you posted?

Comment: I'm assuming my response code and description will be overwritten when the View is returned.

Comment: While m.edmondson is correct with his answer, `Response.End()` will flush everything out and kill the thread, so it doesn't really matter what you do after `Response.End` unless you pass it `false`. It isn't as clear as the answer provided though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This should do what you want:

```
return new HttpUnauthorizedResult();
```

which will return a HTTP 401 to the browser.  [See the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.httpunauthorizedresult.aspx).

Comment: While this worked, I couldn't get things to work like the article suggests. Basically all that happens is the site redirects to the LogOn page as it should when a user isn't authenticated. I guess that solution won't work for MVC.